# Tinker toms inventory

Tags: fallout-4

I purchased some items from tinker tom. One was a weird looking device called MILA, and 3 explosive charges. They are in the miscellaneous section. It appears he doesn't have any quests for me and i have destroyed the institute. What are MilA and/or the explosive charges useful for?

Comment: MILAs are typically given to you by Tinker Tom when you do the radiant quests he gives you. I saw them in his inventory to purchase, but I was never sure why I would buy one when he gives them to me (maybe in case I sold/deleted the one he gave me?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### MILA

MILAs are used for the Railroad Quest [Weathervane](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Weathervane_%28quest%29). In that multi-part quest, you will place a MILA at each of eleven different locations.

You don't actually need to buy any from him in order to do the quest, as he will give you a MILA for each stage. Perhaps it would be useful to buy one if you somehow lost yours.

As the wiki page points out:

> After destroying the Institute, these quests will no longer be available. However, if you choose to reach the ending that keeps the Minutemen, BOS, and Railroad alive and friendly after the Nuclear Option, Tinker Tom will sometimes (but not always) continue to give you these quests.

### Explosive Charges

I'm not sure why Tom sold you explosive charges.

The only reference I see to explosive charges in Fallout 4 is from the Railroad quest [Rockets' Red Glare](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Rockets%27_Red_Glare). Tom gives you explosive charges to destroy the Prydwen.

It's possible he still had these in his inventory from that quest.